# How do you use cucumber with zeus?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, zeus

When I start up zeus, it does not offer `zeus cucumber` as one of the possible commands. Others seem to get this by default; At least I have seen a couple zeus write-ups that show the output from `zeus start` including `zeus cucumber`, and they don't say anything about that having been special or required extra configuration.

I don't really even know where to start to troubleshoot this; I have googled and searched here for "use cucumber with zeus." I get no setup discussions. The only results I get are from people who seem to take for granted that it should be there, and are investigating problems with it not functioning correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [this custom plan](https://github.com/burke/zeus/blob/master/examples/custom_plan/cucumber_plan.rb) file from Zeus. Save it as `custom_plan.rb` at the root of your application:

```
require 'zeus/rails'                   

# 1. Add the cucumber methods (below) to your custom plan (or take this file if
# you don't have an existing custom_plan).
#
# 2. Add the following line to the test_environment section of your zeus.json:
#
#   "cucumber_environment": {"cucumber": []}

class CucumberPlan < Zeus::Rails         
  def cucumber_environment
    ::Rails.env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
    require 'cucumber/rspec/disable_option_parser'
    require 'cucumber/cli/main'
    @cucumber_runtime = Cucumber::Runtime.new
  end

  def cucumber(argv=ARGV)
    cucumber_main = Cucumber::Cli::Main.new(argv.dup)
    had_failures = cucumber_main.execute!(@cucumber_runtime)
    exit_code = had_failures ? 1 : 0
    exit exit_code
  end
end

Zeus.plan = CucumberPlan.new
```

Comment: You left the `require 'zeus/rails'` out of your code fence. But otherwise, wonderful - thank you very much!